# Hover effect on SVG group elements

Tags: html, css, svg

Please excuse my ignorance, SVG is very new to me. I'm trying to get a hover effect on a group of elements in my inline SVG. Each group of elements is a closely positioned set of circles. I can achieve this hover effect with css, but obviously this will only work when the mouse is positioned over a circle. What I want is the effect to work when the mouse is over the whole area that contains the circles, so spaces and circles combined.

```
<style>
svg {
  height: 220px;
  width: 400px;
  background: grey;
}

.na circle,
.as circle {
  fill: white;
}

.na:hover circle {
  fill: blue;
}
</style>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <g class="na">
    <circle cx="35%" cy="2.85%" r="2.8" />
    <circle cx="36.75%" cy="2.85%" r="2.8" />
    .
    .
    <circle cx="38.5%" cy="8.55%" r="2.8" />
    <circle cx="40.25%" cy="8.55%" r="2.8" />
  </g>    
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c3EaX/

See when moving the mouse over a group the hover flickers as you go between circle and space between them.

How would you go about getting the mouse over effect to appear to cover the whole area covered by the group? Is there an SVG element that can be used for this?

Comment: Have you tried `<rect>`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to put something to cover the missing area.

The easier way would be this one:

```
.na circle,
.as circle {
    fill: white;
    stroke: transparent;
    stroke-width: 4px;
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3EaX/1/)

Comment: Awesome. So simple. I'd been trying elaborate things such as an accompanying path with a bit if js to tie the interactions together. Thanks.

Comment: Man that's clever. Wish I could give you more than one vote.

Comment: Good tip, but this wouldn't apply for lines with stroke though!

Answer (score 36):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. I found the following solution:

```
g {
  pointer-events: bounding-box;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
g:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. My only question is "Why this value `bounding-box` is not described by this documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events ?"

Comment: I think this is the better solution and what it is really intended for.

Comment: doesn't work on firefox https://wpt.fyi/results/svg/interact/parsing/pointer-events-valid.svg?label=experimental&label=master&aligned

Answer (score 4):

The answers by @vals and @M_Willett won't work in Firefox v60.0.2 in MacOs (High Sierra). I'm using:

```
g {
  pointer-events: bounding-box;
}
```

In Chrome and it works perfectly. Tried the answer by @vals as well and that doesn't work in Firefox either.

Answer (score 3):

### Use pattern

For the solution, you can use `pattern` which is based on a single circle.

In this case, you do not need to draw a lot of circles to fill the shape.

Difficulties arise when coloring clones of a circle when filling the figure of the SVG pattern.

But it is possible to solve the problem by animating the coloring of the circles inside the pattern.

`<animate attributeName="fill" values="white;dodgerblue" begin="path1.mouseover" dur="0.1s" fill="freeze" />`

```html
<style>
#ptn1 {
fill:dodgerblue;
}
</style>
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >  
<defs>
<pattern id="ptn1"   
  x="0" y="0" width="5" height="5"
  patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<circle cx="3" cy="3" r="2" fill="none" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.5" >
  <animate attributeName="fill" values="white;dodgerblue" begin="path1.mouseover" dur="0.3s" fill="freeze" />
   <animate attributeName="fill" values="dodgerblue;white" begin="path1.mouseout" dur="0.3s" fill="freeze" />
 </circle>
</pattern>
</defs>   

<path id="path1" d="m10 50 v-5h5 v-5h5 v-5h5 v-5h5 v-5h5 v5h5 v5h5 v5h5 v5h5 v5h-45 "  stroke="none" fill="url(#ptn1)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution requires a little JavaScript in order to programmatically get the bounding rectangle of the group. The only drawback is that the hover effect will apply to that rectangle instead of the actual shape of the group.

```js
const group = document.getElementById('group');
const box = group.getBoundingClientRect();

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  const hover = e.clientX > box.left && e.clientX < box.right && e.clientY > box.top && e.clientY < box.bottom;
  if (hover) {
    group.classList.add('hovered');
  } else {
    group.classList.remove('hovered');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

g > circle {
  fill: white;
}

g.hovered > circle {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <g id="group">
    <circle cx="30%" cy="20%" r="5"></circle>
    <circle cx="60%" cy="20%" r="5"></circle>
    <circle cx="45%" cy="50%" r="5"></circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```